# how to get url variable value if variable has & inside it

Tags: php, apache, url, url-rewriting

i have a problem getting the value of an url variable if it has & in it for example i have `cat=Hospitality+&+Tourism+Services`. When i `$_GET` the value of `cat` it stops after Hospitality because i have a & inside it. I encoded url but it still get's me only the first part of variable.

`$cat=$_GET['cat'];
echo $cat;`

this display *Hospitality* instead *Hospitality & Tourism Services*

How can i solve this? thnx in advance!

***edit***
this is my encoded url:
`<a class="btn" href="/<?php echo $nume_categ; ?>/<?php echo urlencode($cat['Nume_Subcat']); ?>.php" role="button"><?php echo $cat['Nume_Heb']; ?><br><?php echo $cat['Nume_Subcat']; ?></a>`

i also have a mod_rewrite for it here it is:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.php$ /produse.php?category=$1&cat=$2 [L]`

Comment: where is the encoded url code?

Comment: You should encode the variables before creating the url.

Comment: it is working on my local. this is the url `http://localhost/work/test_code.php?cat=Hospitality+%26+Tourism+Services`

Comment: Always encode your url before sending, like this: `<a href="somepage.php?cat=<?php echo urlencode("Hospitality & Tourism Services"); ?>">click this link</a>`

Comment: check this http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/u25n-exy6